# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'float'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code:

```
T_ms = range(len(Gx)) * (1 / 500)
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'float'
```

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output ? A range is a generator of multiple numbers, what would be the result when you multiply by a float ?

Comment: i believe you're looking for np.arange

Comment: @azro it should be a column vector to be plot in matplolib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply a math operation on a python `range`, or `list`, use `numpy` lib for that

```
import numpy as np

v = np.arange(10)
print(v)              # [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
print(v * 5)          # [ 0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45]
print(v * (1 / 500))  # [0.    0.002 0.004 0.006 0.008 0.01  0.012 0.014 0.016 0.018]
```

Comment: It worked, @azro thanks!